# Not able to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 4 arrays of images like this:

```
car_image_left = new Image();
car_image_left.src = 'img/car2_left.png';
car_image_mid_left = new Image();
car_image_mid_left.src = 'img/car2_mid_left.png';
car_image_mid_right = new Image();
car_image_mid_right.src = 'img/car2_mid_right.png';
car_image_right = new Image();
car_image_right.src = 'img/car2_right.png';

car_image = [car_image_left,car_image_mid_left,car_image_mid_right,car_image_right];
```

And they are all together in this array:

```
images = [car_image, truck_image, hole_image, banana_image];
```

I'm having a problem in my Drawing function:

```
for (i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++){
    this.context.drawImage(obstacles[i].images[obstacles[i].id][obstacles[i].lane-1],
                           obstacles[i].pos_x - obstacles[i].width/2,
                           obstacles[i].pos_y - obstacles[i].height/2,
                           obstacles[i].width,
                           obstacles[i].height);
}
```

So, basically Obstacles is an array where I store all of my objects, but they're all different, except that each one has an ID.

This is an example of class:

```
function Car(lane) {
    this.id = 0;
    this.lane = lane;
    this.height = 108.75;
    this.width = 99;
    this.pos_x = CENTER;
    this.pos_y = -350;
    this.car_image = images[this.id][this.lane-1];
}
```

Comment: to debug this, first console log your original array if that's  correct then log this.id and this.lane , you will know whats going wrong

Comment: Do all of the objects in array has lane, pos_x/y, height and width? Basically we don't have enough information to help you. We need to see your actual code. It seems to me like the images array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

An index is out of bounds an you get undefined, I would think this is the line:

```
this.car_image = images[this.id][this.lane-1];
```

as a solution put this before the line and you should understand what exactly went wrong:

```
console.log(images.length);
console.log(this.id);
console.log(images[this.id]);
console.log(images[this.id].length);
console.log(this.lane-1);
```

by confronting lengths and indices you should see which goes out of range.